# Uniqueness of collar neighborhoods for non-compact boundary case in smooth setting

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

> Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $f_0, f_1 \colon [0, 1] \times
>  \partial M \to M$ be two smooth embeddings that are the identity map
> on $\partial M \times\{0\} = \partial M$ . If $\partial M$ is
> **non-compact** does there exist a diffeotopy $H \colon M × [0, 1] \to M$ relative to $\partial M$ from $H_0=\text{id}_M$ to a diffeomorphism
> $H_1\colon M\to M$ with $H_1\circ f_0=f_1$?

*The case for compact boundary can be found in most textbooks.* Can someone suggest to me some references for the non-compact boundary case?

Comment: As stated the answer is no. You also need to assume that the image of the collaring maps is closed. Otherwise it is fairly straightforward to find counterexamples. I also spent some time trying to find a reference for this statement, but I was not successful either.

Comment: Maybe the boundary needs to be slightly stronger than paracompact?